# a questions on template traits (related to numeric computation on double and complex number)

Tags: c++, templates, traits

What I would like to do is simply computing error between two vectors, but the input vectors could contain complex or real numbers. So far I have following solution.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 computeError(const std::vector<T1> & in1,
                           const std::vector<T2> & in2)
{
    int size = in1.size();
    T1 error = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    error += std::abs(in1[i]- in2[i]);
    }
    return error;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 computeError(const std::vector<complex<T1> > & in1,
                           const std::vector<complex<T2> > & in2)
{
    int size = in1.size();
    T1 error = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    error += std::abs(in1[i] - in2[i]);
    }
    return error;
};
```

So basically, I implemented two functions. But they are quite similar to each other. I am wondering if there is a way to implement only one function covering both cases.

Thanks

Comment: The two functions give different results when applied to the complex case, so what you're really trying to do is template specialization, so I think the only way to do it with one function would be an ugly hack much worse than what you have.

Comment: Drop the second one; the first one works for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work with C++11

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::conditional<is_class<T1>, T1:value_type, T1> computeError(const std::vector<T1> & in1,
                           const std::vector<T2> & in2)
{
    int size = in1.size();
    typename std::conditional<is_class<T1>, T1:value_type, T1> error = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    error += std::abs(in1[i]- in2[i]);
    }
    return error;
};
```